# Mapping - ElasticSearch [7+]

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I have solved a lot of this issue I am now left wondering what is the issue and what I am possibly doing wrong.

The console query I am aiming to recreate using NEST is:

```
    {
  "tdindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "documentModel" : {
        "properties" : {
          "accessControl" : {
            "type" : "boolean",
            "copy_to" : [
              "copyTo"
            ]
          },
          "comments" : {
            "properties" : {
              "comment" : {
                "type" : "text",
                 "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
                "copy_to" : [
                  "copyTo"
                ]},
              "createDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
 "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
                "copy_to" : [
                  "copyTo"
                ]},
              "user" : {
                "type" : "text",
                 "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
                "copy_to" : [
                  "copyTo"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "copyTo" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "documentType" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
            "copy_to" : [
              "copyTo"
            ]
          },
          "filename" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
            "copy_to" : [
              "copyTo"
            ]
          },
          "folderID" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "copy_to" : [
              "copyTo"
            ]
          },
          "metadata" : {
            "properties" : {
              "key" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                },
                "copy_to" : [
                  "copyTo"
                ]
              },
              "value" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                },
                "copy_to" : [
                  "copyTo"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "uploadDate" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "copy_to" : [
              "copyTo"
            ]
          },
          "uploadUser" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
            "copy_to" : [
              "copyTo"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I currently have the following Console query being created my nest:

```
  {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "folderid": {
        "copy_to": [
          "CopyTo"
        ],
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "type": "text"
      },
      "filename": {
        "copy_to": [
          "CopyTo"
        ],
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "type": "text"
      },
      "documenttype": {
        "copy_to": [
          "CopyTo"
        ],
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "type": "text"
      },
      "uploaddate": {
        "copy_to": [
          "CopyTo"
        ],
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "type": "text"
      },
      "uploaduser": {
        "copy_to": [
          "CopyTo"
        ],
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "type": "text"
      },
      "comments": {
        "properties": {
          "createdate": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "comment": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "user": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        "copy_to": [
          "CopyTo"
        ],
        "type": "nested"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        "copy_to": [
          "CopyTo"
        ],
        "type": "nested"
      },
      "CopyTo": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see it is leaving out the DocumentModel…

The NEST code I am using is:

```
_elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexParameters.IndexName, c =>
            {
                c.Map<DocumentModel>(m => m

                   .Properties(ps => ps

                                      .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.FolderID).CopyTo(n => n.Field(f => f.CopyTo)).Fields(fd => fd.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword").IgnoreAbove(256))))
                      .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Filename).CopyTo(n => n.Field(f => f.CopyTo)).Fields(fd => fd.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword").IgnoreAbove(256))))
                      .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.DocumentType).CopyTo(n => n.Field(f => f.CopyTo)).Fields(fd => fd.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword").IgnoreAbove(256))))
                      .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.UploadDate).CopyTo(n => n.Field(f => f.CopyTo)).Fields(fd => fd.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword").IgnoreAbove(256))))
                      .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.uploadUser).CopyTo(n => n.Field(f => f.CopyTo)).Fields(fd => fd.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword").IgnoreAbove(256))))
                      .Nested<Comments>(cm => cm.Name(n => n.Comments).AutoMap().CopyTo(n => n.Field(f => f.CopyTo)))
                      .Nested<Metadata>(md => md.Name(n => n.Metadata).AutoMap().CopyTo(n => n.Field(f => f.CopyTo)))
                      .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.CopyTo)))
```

My DocumentModel looks like this (I cannot use [ElasticsearchType(Name = "documentModel")] for some reason in the model not sure if this is part of the cause of the problem?):

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    [Text(Name = "filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "folderid")]
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "uploaduser")]
    public string uploadUser { get; set; }
    [Date(Format = "MMddyyyy")]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "documenttype")]
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    [Boolean(NullValue = false)]
    public bool AccessControl { get; set; }
    [Nested]
    public List<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    [Nested]
    public List<Metadata> Metadata { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "CopyTo")]
    public string CopyTo { get; set; }


}

public class Comments
{
    [Date(Format = "MMddyyyy")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "user")]
    public string User { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    [Text(Name = "key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The error I get from the Console when running the query is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [metadata : {copy_to=[CopyTo], type=nested, properties={value={type=text}, key={type=text}}}] [filename : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [comments : {copy_to=[CopyTo], type=nested, properties={createdate={type=date}, comment={type=text}, user={type=text}}}] [uploaddate : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [CopyTo : {type=text}] [documenttype : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [folderid : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [uploaduser : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [properties]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [metadata : {copy_to=[CopyTo], type=nested, properties={value={type=text}, key={type=text}}}] [filename : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [comments : {copy_to=[CopyTo], type=nested, properties={createdate={type=date}, comment={type=text}, user={type=text}}}] [uploaddate : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [CopyTo : {type=text}] [documenttype : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [folderid : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [uploaduser : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [metadata : {copy_to=[CopyTo], type=nested, properties={value={type=text}, key={type=text}}}] [filename : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [comments : {copy_to=[CopyTo], type=nested, properties={createdate={type=date}, comment={type=text}, user={type=text}}}] [uploaddate : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [CopyTo : {type=text}] [documenttype : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [folderid : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}] [uploaduser : {copy_to=[CopyTo], fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
```

Any Ideas?

I Assume the issue is due to the Map?

P.S.  I am running Kibana 6.7.1 and Elastic 6.7.1 over localhost. I am running the query (from the JSON object created by the request using NEST)

Comment: Which version of Nest are you using? The current release does not yet support Elastic 7, but there is an alpha available if you enable pre-release versions in Nuget. You can see the supported versions here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

Comment: Turns out I'm using the NEST 7.0.0-aplha... I have managed to get the Console query looking closer to what I want but still no joy... I will be sure to update this post if I make any headway... Cheers

Comment: Please do not completely change your question text after you find a solution, as you are removing the context of the original question.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the whole context I realised the problem wasn't specifically addressed in the question, and when I posted the question I realized the structure of the query I previously posted was incorrect, the correct code above makes the question a simpler one being why am I getting a mapper_parsing_exception and if not being able to use [ElasticsearchType(Name = "documentModel")]  is anything to so with the parsing issue and the documentModel being left out... if you seen both questions why post what you have, it helps no one... don't post unless you can help solve the issue...

Comment: As for the missing "documentModel" key: ES 7.0 by default disallows specifying document type by defaulting the `include_type_name` query parameter to false. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html.

Your actual issue probably has to do with how you are passing the mapping to Elasticsearch. You'll need to be more precise with what you mean by "The error I get from the Console when running the query" - what console? What endpoint? How are you running the query?

Comment: I just tried it on my cluster; the mapping that nest generated for you is in fact correct and creates an index as expected. Take a look at the examples at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html to see how you should make your request to ES. There's a tiny possibility that this is a nest bug. re: "don't post unless you can help solve the issue": as a reciprocal, don't ask a question on StackOverflow unless you are prepared to contribute to the site.

Comment: Cheers @Backgammon I will have another go and update my post in the morning; as for further explaining "The error I get from the Console when running the query", I am running Kibana 6.7.1 and Elastic 6.7.1 over localhost. I am running the query (from the JSON object created by the request using NEST)… As you have said the syntax seems to be acceptable (I will have to take a closer look tomorrow)

Comment: Looking at your code (I'm not familiar with NEST specifically) it looks like you're missing a `Mappings` call before `Map`? See e.g. the `createIndex` call example on this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html

Comment: @Backgammon I think its depreciated in NEST 7.x(Elastic), Nest now states "CreateIndexDescriptor.Mapings(Func<MappingsDescriptor, <ITypeMapping>)' is obsolete: 'Mapping is no longer a dictionary in 7.x, please use the simplified Map()…" been a pain finding the new syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Elasticsearch 6.7.1, please use the latest 6.x NEST client, which [is 6.7.0 at this time](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/6.7.0). Major versions of the client are compatible with major versions of Elasticsearch.

With NEST 6.7.0, the mapping would be something like

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "tdindex";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var visitor = new MyVisitor();  

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<DocumentModel>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap(visitor)
                .Properties(ps => ps
                    .Nested<Comments>(cm => cm
                        .Name(n => n.Comments)
                        .AutoMap(visitor)
                    )
                    .Nested<Metadata>(md => md
                        .Name(n => n.Metadata)
                        .AutoMap(visitor)
                    )
                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.CopyTo))
                )
            )
        )
    );

}

public class MyVisitor : NoopPropertyVisitor
{
    public override void Visit(ITextProperty property, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase attribute)
    {
        base.Visit(property, propertyInfo, attribute);
        property.CopyTo = Infer.Fields<DocumentModel>(f => f.CopyTo);
        property.Fields = new Properties
        {
            { "keyword", new KeywordProperty { IgnoreAbove = 256  } }
        };
    }
}

[ElasticsearchType(Name = "documentModel")]
public class DocumentModel
{
    [Text(Name = "filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "folderid")]
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "uploaduser")]
    public string uploadUser { get; set; }
    [Date(Format = "MMddyyyy")]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "documenttype")]
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    [Boolean(NullValue = false)]
    public bool AccessControl { get; set; }
    [Nested]
    public List<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    [Nested]
    public List<Metadata> Metadata { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "copyTo")]
    public string CopyTo { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    [Date(Format = "MMddyyyy")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "user")]
    public string User { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    [Text(Name = "key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Since all of the text mappings except `CopyTo` property have a keyword multi_fields and copy_to to copy to the `CopyTo` field, the easiest way to [define this is with a visitor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/visitor-pattern-mapping.html). First, `Automap()` is called, passing the visitor. Automapping will pick up the attribute mappings on the models, and the Visit methods on the visitor will allow us to override any of these. Next, `Properties()` will override any mappings from the automapping process.

The final output mapping is

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/tdindex?pretty=true 
{
  "mappings": {
    "documentModel": {
      "properties": {
        "filename": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": [
            "copyTo"
          ],
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "folderid": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": [
            "copyTo"
          ],
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "uploaduser": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": [
            "copyTo"
          ],
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "uploadDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "MMddyyyy"
        },
        "documenttype": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": [
            "copyTo"
          ],
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "accessControl": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "null_value": false
        },
        "comments": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "createDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "MMddyyyy"
            },
            "comment": {
              "type": "text",
              "copy_to": [
                "copyTo"
              ],
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "user": {
              "type": "text",
              "copy_to": [
                "copyTo"
              ],
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "metadata": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "text",
              "copy_to": [
                "copyTo"
              ],
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "text",
              "copy_to": [
                "copyTo"
              ],
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "copyTo": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The syntax for NEST 7.x, which is compatible with Elasticsearch 7.x, is the same; there are a couple of things that are obsolete that *can* be changed to remove the warnings, but the 6.x syntax works as is

```
client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
    // remove .Mappings()
    .Map<DocumentModel>(mm => mm
        .AutoMap(visitor)
        .Properties(ps => ps
            .Nested<Comments>(cm => cm
                .Name(n => n.Comments)
                .AutoMap(visitor)
            )
            .Nested<Metadata>(md => md
                .Name(n => n.Metadata)
                .AutoMap(visitor)
            )
            .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.CopyTo))
        )
    )
);

// Use RelationName instead of Name
[ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "documentModel")]
public class DocumentModel
{
    [Text(Name = "filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "folderid")]
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "uploaduser")]
    public string uploadUser { get; set; }
    [Date(Format = "MMddyyyy")]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "documenttype")]
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    [Boolean(NullValue = false)]
    public bool AccessControl { get; set; }
    [Nested]
    public List<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    [Nested]
    public List<Metadata> Metadata { get; set; }
    [Text(Name = "copyTo")]
    public string CopyTo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is exactaly what I need, the issue as with my code above (of which im not sure I made all that clear...) is that [ElasticsearchType(Name = "documentModel")] is showing an Error: "The Type or namespace 'Name' could not be found."... I am not sure if this is due to using NEST 7.0-alpha... What version of NEST are you using?

Comment: I'm using 6.7.0. It will be due to using 7.0.0-alpha1 which is not compatible with Elasticsearch 6.7.0

Comment: I will try to downgrade my NEST, I will be back swiftly with an outcome

Comment: With NEST 6.7.0 the code from you solution and mine both work; that being said I would like to see the syntax for 7.x if anybody knows it? For now I will stick with 6.7.0 and implement you visitor class, cheers for that Russ if somebody doesn't get back to me with 7.x syntax soon ill give you the Answer

Comment: the same syntax will work in 7.x. There are a couple of Obsolete warnings which the code can be changed to fix.

Comment: when I use [ElasticsearchType(Name = "documentModel")] its showing an Error: "The Type or namespace 'Name' could not be found."... It has stopped putting a red swiggle under the Name when I downgrade from 6.7.0.

Comment: If you're running against Elasticsearch 7.x, try with 7.0.0-alpha2. `Name` was added back but obsoleted: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/3702

Comment: I used you automapper with the visitor obiect, going to use 6.7.0 until 7.0 is release beyond alpha cheers